# not only, but also

Tags: conjunctions

With reference to the principle of balance in the use of "not only, but also", can someone help me judge whether the following is correct:

> Not only are students encouraged to enhance their understanding of the
>   Constiution and study it thoroughly but also their civic awareness can
>   be promoted.

Comment: What you have isn’t wrong, but it really isn’t parallel at all, which would be preferable stylistically.

Comment: I like that better, yes.

Comment: Louise Liu: it looks as if you offered an alternative phrasing in a comment. Could you add that to your answer? It always helps if you can include some example or explanation to show whether (and why) you think the citation is improperly phrased, or how you think it might be improved.

Comment: Yes, I would like to edit it but found there is no editing function for comments, so I deleted it. The alternative version is: "Not only are students encouraged to enhance their understanding of the Constiution and study it thoroughly but  their civic awareness can also be promoted."

Answer (score 2):

According to [examples used by Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/not-only-but-also), that sentence, by format, is correct. Although, it is a bit clunky.

The example doesn't use a comma in this case, but I personally would, since it is combining two independent sentences.

Comment: Great. The reference to the website is useful.

Comment: @LouisLiu No problem.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is one of the least known of English Language grammar Rules.
I see this Rule violated all the time.

I learned this back in High School:
The Rule is, simply put, whenever one uses "not only" one must, in the same sentence,
eventually follow with "but also".  That's it.